# Is it possible to set specific network settings depending on the WiFi I am connected to with Windows?

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns

I just got a new Surface Book today with Windows 10 Pro. I set up a domain on my Synology DiskStation (I am planning to get another Windows based machine later) and connected the device to it. This works fine so far. However, I need specific DNS settings for my home network, so I entered the IP addresses of my DiskStation into the adapter settings.

When I now connect to another network where my DiskStation isn't available, I have to manually set the DNS to autodetect and reset it to my DS when I'm back home.

macOS has "network locations" one can switch, and using an application like "ControlPlane" I can handle this automatically when I connect to the specific network.

Is anything like this possible on Windows 10, too?

## Workaround: Using VPN

My DiskStation also has OpenVPN running, and thus two separate IP addresses (one that is routed to the outside for connecting from on the go).

So, I just added an OpenVPN config and used its first IP address as its "remote" address, and added:

```
dhcp-option DOMAIN mysynologydomain
dhcp-option DNS the.second.ip.address
```

When I'm now connected to my network via WiFi instead of wired, I just use OpenVPN to connect to that configuration and my DNS is set up correctly.

But I'd appreciate a less "roundabout" way.

Answer (score 2):

Specify your default domain and DNS on the DHCP server.  Then push it to all dhcp clients. Then set a static IP to the synology.

Comment: While this would work, my DHCP server is a router from my ISP that doesn't provide me these settings. Maybe I should disable it and enable a DHCP Server on my DiskStation.

Comment: Yeah definitely offload the duty then.

Comment: You should really avoid using an ISP-provided device as anything other than a gateway, using your own router inside your network so you can control how it operates and don't expose anything through a device that is a high-value target, often with long-term security risk exposure and no ability to manage it to address issues.